# How do I use secondary constructors when I need to do operations on the parameter

Tags: kotlin, constructor

I have this class (provides an implementation for a rational number) and I am having problems writing a secondary constructor - I need to do some computation on the value: String that I pass as a parameter and I don't know how to write that.

This is what I have right now, and it works. Most cases. The case that fails is when the string doesn't contain "/" aka when the denominator is 1.

```
data class Rational(val num:BigInteger, val den: BigInteger){
   private val numerator
   private val denominator
   init{
       denominator = when (den){
           0.toBigInteger -> thrown IllegalArgumentException()
           else -> den
       }
       numerator = num
   }
   constructor (value: String) :
        this(value.split("/")[0].toBigInteger(), value.split("/")[1].toBigInteger())
}
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Why does it have to be a constructor instead of a factory method? And even if it does, you can extract the logic into a helper (with slight complication because you need two values):

```
data class Rational(val num:BigInteger, val den: BigInteger){ 
   ...
   private constructor (pair: Pair<BigInteger, BigInteger>) : this(pair.first, pair.second)
   constructor (value: String) :
        this(parseString(value))

   companion object {
      private fun parseString(value: String) =
         if (value.contains("/")) {
             val parts = value.split("/")
             Pair(parts[0].toBigInteger(), parts[1].toBigInteger())
         } else
             Pair(value.toBigInteger(), 1.toBigInteger())
   }
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea! I'll try this